# How to override __repr__ when inheriting from OrderedDict?

Tags: python, inheritance, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to implement pretty looking results from analysis while working in interactive shell (`IPython` in my case). This is some sort of mapping, also the order is important to me, so I have tried to inherit from `OrderedDict` and to override `__repr__` method but this approach did not work. The minimum test example:

```
 In[1]: from collections import OrderedDict

 In[2]: class Result(OrderedDict):
            def __repr__(self):
                if self.keys():
                    report = []
                    for k, v in self.items():
                        report.append(k.ljust(10) + ': ' + repr(v))
                    return "\n".join(report)
                else:
                    return self.__class__.__name__ + "()"

 In[3]: res = Result()
        res['all'] = 10
        res['some'] = 11
        res
Out[3]: Result([('all', 10), ('some', 11)])
```

But when I inherit from `dict` (`class Result(dict):`) this approach works as expected, and the result looks as:

```
Out[3]: all       : 10
        some      : 11
```

But the order is not guaranteed. I have no idea, why the first approach does not work?

**EDIT:**
Python 3.6.1
IPython 6.0.0

Comment: I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: I can't reproduce in python 2.7 - what version are you in?

Comment: It looks like the problem only occurs in IPython.

Comment: The `IPython` shell is so permanent tool for me. I did not even get the idea - where the roots of the problem lie. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IPython has some "magic" that uses its own pretty-printer instead of the default `__repr__`.  You can turn this off by using `%pprint off` and then your `__repr__` will work.  You could also try overriding `_repr_pretty` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565535/ipython-ignores-objects-repr-when-printing-it).  Your code already works fine outside IPython.

Answer (score 2):

Your `__repr__` is fine, but IPython's pretty-printer is overriding it. You can explicitly print the `repr`:

```
print repr(your_object)
```

or disable IPython's pretty-printing:

```
# Toggles pretty-printing.
%pprint
```